# Generate GUID for Primary key automatically In EF5

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-5

I'm using Guids as primary key for the entities in my database, using the model binding feature of asp.net 4.5 web forms when im inserting a record in the database using entity framework 5 im doing something like

```
public void onInsert([Control("ControlID")] int? countryID){

 if(countryID.hasValue){
    var DbEntityToInsert = new DbEntity(); //where DbEntity is the class generated by the EF
    TryUpdateModel(DbEntityToInsert);
    DbEntityToInsert.GuidPK = Guid.NewGuid();
    if(Page.ModelState.IsValid){
     using(var db = new DatabaseContext()){
      db.Add(DbEntityToInsert);
      db.Save();
     }//using ends
    }//modelstate.isvalid if ends
  }//countryid.hasvalue ends
 }//main method ends
```

now i wanted to ask is there a way i can tell EF to generate a Guid for the PK while inserting a new record so i dont have to write the line

```
  DbEntityToInsert.GuidPK = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to override `SaveChanges` in your derived context. The main task is to find out if an entity has a `GuidPK` property as primary key. Here is an attempt using reflection:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    this.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

    var addedEntities = this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added)
        .Select(e => new
        {
            Entity = e.Entity,
            PropertyInfo = e.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("GuidPK")
        })
        .Where(x => x.PropertyInfo != null && x.PropertyInfo.CanWrite);

    foreach (var x in addedEntities)
        x.PropertyInfo.SetValue(x.Entity, Guid.NewGuid());

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

To avoid reflection here you could have a common interface that is implemented by all your entities that use a `GuidPK` property as PK:

```
public interface IEntityWithGuidPK
{
    Guid GuidPK { get; set; }
}

public class DbEntity : IEntityWithGuidPK
{
    public Guid GuidPK { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Then the code in `SaveChanges` could be:

```
    //...

    var addedEntities = this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added &&
            e.Entity is IEntityWithGuidPK)
        .Select(e => e.Entity as IEntityWithGuidPK);

    foreach (var e in addedEntities)
        e.GuidPK = Guid.NewGuid();

    //...
```